# There are let suppose 5 duplicate rows in table example as below I want to to update all to NULL except one row - sql query

Tags: sql

```
Location | Entity_id
UK       | 1320
UK       | 1320
UK       | 1320
UK       | 1320
UK       | 1320
```

I want to retain first row entity_ID only and all others rows to NULL.SQL QUERY to do that ?

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: How do you know which row is first? (Any timestamp/id column available?)

Comment: Does it really need to be in one single query? Or else you can select the duplicates, get unique keys and set to null in a second query..

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT Id, 
       Location, 
       Entity_id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Entity_id ORDER BY Id ASC) rn
FROM Table
WHERE Entity_id = 1320
)

UPDATE CTE
SET Entity_id = NULL
WHERE rn > 1
```

Assume You have a primary key as Id

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also..
for generalize query 
;

```
WITH update_entity AS 
(
    SELECT row_number_temp = ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER( 
                  PARTITION entity_id
                  ORDER BY  entity_id ASC), * 
    FROM dbo.table1
)
```

`Update  update_entity  set entity_id=NULL WHERE  row_number_temp > 1`

If you want to do for specific entity id then you pass the value of entity_id

`Update  update_entity  set entity_id=NULL WHERE  row_number_temp > 1 and  entity_id =1320`